# How to use Array.prototype.reduce in generator with yield inside?

Tags: javascript, generator

I would like to run a reduce function in which I want pause it via yield.
Here is what I tried and failed because error:
`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier`

```
function* abc() {
    return [1,2,3].reduce((accumulator, currentValue) => {
        accumulator.push(currentValue); 
        yield currentValue;
        return accumulator;
    }, []);
}
```

Comment: You can’t. `yield` doesn’t cross function boundaries. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: @FelixKling I want pause and resume the function while examine current states to determine whether resuming or not.

Comment: You can build your own version of `reduce` which can do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't `yield` inside a callback - any `yield`s must be directly inside a generator function. You'll have to transform the `reduce` into something else.

```js
function* abc() {
  const accumulator = [];
  for (const currentValue of [1, 2, 3]) {
    yield currentValue;
    accumulator.push(currentValue);
  }
  // do something with accumulator?
}

console.log(...abc());
```

Comment: I see. Is there any proposal active that suggests that array function can accept generator function?

Comment: I haven't seen one. It would probably be difficult to impossible to specify, unless the built-in array methods were given a special exception (and that would be *weird*).